# Integer cannot be cast to Boolean when use Preferences

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Preferences in Android. When i change a switch, i put a boolean:

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_, isChecked ->
        if(isChecked){
            sharedPref?.let {
                with(it.edit()) {
                    putBoolean("sw1", true)
                    apply()
                }
            }
        }else{
            sharedPref?.let {
                with(it.edit()) {
                    putBoolean("sw1", false)
                    apply()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i get it:

```
val sw1 = sharedPref?.getBoolean("sw1", false)
sw1?.let {
        switch1.isChecked = sw1
    }
```

But i receive a error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Boolean

Comment: try this  `switch1.isChecked =  sharedPref?.getBoolean("sw1", false)`

Comment: val sw1 : Boolean = sharedPref?.getBoolean("sw1", false) You can also try with this

Comment: Were you using putInt previously?

Comment: Thanks!! I tried in 2 ways but it's does not working

Comment: @Bharath Kumar it's fine if i use putInt()

Comment: Sloved!! I used putInt() before, I clear data and it's working

Comment: Thanks for help me

Comment: Welcome! I added more details in the answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data in shared preferences is stored using putInt() and getBoolean() is used to retrieve the data for same key, then ClassCastException will occur.

It can be solved in 2 ways.

1. The shared preferences data can be cleared. From Settings->App info-> Your app -> Clear Data.
2. In case there is a need to change the preferences data type to boolean then make sure that putBoolean() is called before getBoolean().